# Questions quickly flagged as off-topic with "unclear what you're asking"

Tags: discussion

Some questions are quickly flagged with the very generic "unclear what you're asking".

For example after two hours this was flagged: [How to calculate circulating supply for geth private network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70529/how-to-calculate-circulating-supply-for-geth-private-network)

In this particular case for me it is clearly on-topic. An can be answered in a generic way.

It worries me that it is flagged before any interaction to retrieve more details from the question author.

Answer (score 5):

A robot not in our control, decides to put questions in the Low Quality queue.

It usually takes 5 people to vote on closing a question as "unclear what you're asking".

If a question does get closed, anyone can try to reopen it: it will be put on a queue and usually with 4 other people, the question can get reopened again. When the question is closed, the asker will get information about how to improve the question. If the asker edits the question, it will be put in the queue for people to examine if it should be reopened.

The robot and the process isn't perfect, but it seems good enough.

Comment: Worth noting that the bot will put any question with a very short body, like that one, into the VLQ review queue but without issuing a flag reason.  What often happens is that the first reviewer in the queue picks "Unclear" then others follow.